# Microsoft speech NuGet package doesn't work in C++ project

Tags: c++, azure, nuget

I'm trying to use the Azure cognitive services speech api in a C++ project and followed the instructions to install the NuGet package (Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech) via [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/setup-platform?pivots=programming-language-cpp&tabs=dotnet%2Cwindows%2Cjre%2Cbrowser). After that, I followed one of the [basic tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-cpp), but my C++ project doesn't recognise the Microsoft namespaces, like
[image]

No references seem to be added to the project and no files were added in the external dependencies directory. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you only `#include <iostream>`. Indeed, the `iostream` header does not contain any `Microsoft` namespaces. As is described in [Get started with speech translation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-translation?tabs=script%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-cpp#import-dependencies), you need to `#include <speechapi_cxx.h>`.

There seems to be an omission in the [Get started with speech-to-text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-cpp) documentation: it doesn't contain the ***Import dependencies*** section similar to the one in the [Get started with text-to-speech](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=script%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-cpp) and other related documentation pages there (like [Speech Translation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-translation?tabs=script%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-cpp#import-dependencies), [Speaker Recognition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speaker-recognition?tabs=script&pivots=programming-language-cpp#import-dependencies), etc.). You may want to submit a bug report to Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow missed that part of the tutorial...

Comment: @Jelle I've updated my answer. Seems there's an omission in Microsoft's docs.